# Model Does Not Animate Properly In Unity Game After Saved and Exported From Blender

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 3d, blender

I am creating a character for a Unity game (Ultimate Epic Battle Simulator 2) with premade animations for a humanoid. I use Blender to create and rig my models. Few weeks ago, my models would animate properly in the game; now, my models do not animate at all, stuck in their pose while sliding in the game. If I remove the leg's parenting to the hip, the character's hip will move in-game, but not the arms and legs. Models downloaded from the Internet animated fine in-game, it's just my Blender models that have this issue, which made me hypothesize it is a Blender issue.

I tried using .fbk models I got from the Internet to try replicating them in Blender. The external models always animate properly in-game, but when I imported them into Blender, save, load saved file and exported it as .fbk without editing anything, the exported file does not animate properly in the game, just as the models I made in Blender.

I used Mixamo for rigging. There were a few times the rigged models animate properly in-game, but currently even Mixamo rigged models do not animate if the models were from Blender.

Root motion has no effect whether it is toggled or not. Animations also work well in Unity's animation inspector, it's in the game that animation problem occurs.

Is this due to Blender changing bone heirarchy? Or is there some hidden settings in Blender or Unity that's causing this?

The game dev's code for modding their game:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AllMeshes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (AllMeshes[i].Skinned != null/* || AllMeshes[i].MeshRenderer != null*/)
            {
                if (AllMeshes[i].Skinned != null) AllMeshes[i].mats = AllMeshes[i].Skinned.sharedMaterials;
               // if (AllMeshes[i].MeshRenderer != null) AllMeshes[i].mats = AllMeshes[i].MeshRenderer.sharedMaterials;
            }

        }

        if(AllMeshes.Length != LastArraycount)
        {
            if(AllMeshes.Length > LastArraycount)
            {
                for (int i = AllMeshes.Length - (AllMeshes.Length - LastArraycount); i < AllMeshes.Length; i++)
                {
                    AllMeshes[i].RenderPriority = Priority.Med;
                }
            }

            LastArraycount = AllMeshes.Length;
        }

        

        if (SeperateSubMeshes)
        {
            SeperateSubMeshes = false;
            List<MeshProps> nm = new List<MeshProps>();
            for (int i = 0; i < AllMeshes.Length; i++)
            {
                GameObject[] newobs = SeparateSubmeshes(AllMeshes[i].Skinned.gameObject);

                for (int s = 0; s < newobs.Length; s++)
                {
                    MeshProps nmm = new MeshProps();
                    nmm.Skinned = newobs[s].GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
                    nm.Add(nmm);
                }

            }

            AllMeshes = nm.ToArray();

        }
    }



    public GameObject[] SeparateSubmeshes(GameObject sourceObject)
    {
        SkinnedMeshRenderer sourceRenderer = sourceObject.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();

        if (sourceRenderer == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No SkinnedMeshRenderer found on the source object.");
            return null;
        }

        Mesh sourceMesh = sourceRenderer.sharedMesh;
        Material[] sourceMaterials = sourceRenderer.sharedMaterials;

        if (sourceMesh == null || sourceMesh.subMeshCount <= 1)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No sub-meshes found to separate.");
            return null;
        }

        List<GameObject> createdObjects = new List<GameObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceMesh.subMeshCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject newObject = new GameObject(sourceMesh.name + " Submesh "+i, typeof(SkinnedMeshRenderer));
            newObject.transform.SetParent(sourceObject.transform.parent, false);
            newObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            newObject.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            newObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

            SkinnedMeshRenderer newRenderer = newObject.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();

            Mesh newMesh = CreateMeshFromSubmesh(sourceMesh, i);
            newRenderer.sharedMesh = newMesh;

          

            newRenderer.sharedMaterials = new Material[] { sourceMaterials[i] };
            newRenderer.bones = sourceRenderer.bones;
            newRenderer.rootBone = sourceRenderer.rootBone;

            createdObjects.Add(newObject);

            //SAVE MESH
            newMesh.name = transform.name + "-"+ newObject.name;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(newMesh, "Assets"+"/"+SaveMeshFolder+"/"+ newMesh.name);
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
#endif
        }

        return createdObjects.ToArray();
    }

    private Mesh CreateMeshFromSubmesh(Mesh sourceMesh, int submeshIndex)
    {
        if (submeshIndex < 0 || submeshIndex >= sourceMesh.subMeshCount)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Invalid submesh index.");
            return null;
        }

        Mesh newMesh = new Mesh();
        if (sourceMesh.triangles.Length > 150000) newMesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;

        int[] sourceTriangles = sourceMesh.GetTriangles(submeshIndex);

        // Collect unique vertex indices from the submesh
        HashSet<int> uniqueIndices = new HashSet<int>(sourceTriangles);
        int[] newIndexRemap = new int[sourceMesh.vertexCount];
        Vector3[] sourceVertices = sourceMesh.vertices;
        Vector2[] sourceUv = sourceMesh.uv;
        Vector3[] sourceNormals = sourceMesh.normals;
        Vector4[] sourceTangents = sourceMesh.tangents;
        BoneWeight[] sourceBoneWeights = sourceMesh.boneWeights;

        // Create new vertex attribute arrays
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[uniqueIndices.Count];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[uniqueIndices.Count];
        Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[uniqueIndices.Count];
        Vector4[] tangents = new Vector4[uniqueIndices.Count];
        BoneWeight[] boneWeights = new BoneWeight[uniqueIndices.Count];

        int newIndex = 0;
        foreach (int vertexIndex in uniqueIndices)
        {
            newIndexRemap[vertexIndex] = newIndex;
            vertices[newIndex] = sourceVertices[vertexIndex];
            uv[newIndex] = sourceUv[vertexIndex];
            normals[newIndex] = sourceNormals[vertexIndex];
            tangents[newIndex] = sourceTangents[vertexIndex];
            boneWeights[newIndex] = sourceBoneWeights[vertexIndex];
            newIndex++;
        }

        // Remap the triangles to the new vertex indices
        int[] triangles = new int[sourceTriangles.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceTriangles.Length; i++)
        {
            triangles[i] = newIndexRemap[sourceTriangles[i]];
        }

        newMesh.vertices = vertices;
        newMesh.uv = uv;
        newMesh.normals = normals;
        newMesh.tangents = tangents;
        newMesh.boneWeights = boneWeights;
        newMesh.triangles = triangles;
        newMesh.bindposes = sourceMesh.bindposes;

        newMesh.RecalculateBounds();

        return newMesh;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position + (Vector3.up * collisionSettings.CollisionHeight * 0.5f), new Vector3(collisionSettings.CollisionWidth, collisionSettings.CollisionHeight, collisionSettings.CollisionWidth));
    }

}
```

Comment: When you preview the animation in the inspector does it run ok? Please show the code you're using to drive the anims.

Comment: Yes, animations work in the inspector.

Comment: I don't see anything in the posted code that actually controls animations. Also, because you are 'cloning' the mesh with your vertices matix the skinning would not apply. What is it you want to do exactly?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm not entirely sure how the code works. I want my models to animate, and I want to troubleshoot whether Blender is preventing it or not, cuz I can't figure why a model can animate properly until I saved it in Blender.

Comment: Normally you'd use the built in components: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html